# AngularJS and asynchronous operations

Tags: javascript, angularjs, asynchronous

I'm building a very basic app with AngularJS. One of the things I need to do is remove items from a list. In an attempt to do this, I've written the following code:

```
$scope.removeItem = function(item) {
  var toRemove = -1;
  angular.forEach($scope.items, function(_item, key) {
    if (item === _item) {
      toRemove = key;
      return false;
    }
  });       

  if (toRemove >= 0) {
    $scope.items.splice(i, 1);
    return true;
  }
  return false;
};
```

This seems to be working. However, my data set is relative small. The thing I can't figure out is the `.forEach`. Does that function operate asynchronously? In other words, could my code below the `angular.forEach` execute before the `.forEach` has completed? I keep hearing about asynchronous operations. However, I don't understand when that happens and when it doesn't.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not asynchronous. `angular.forEach` does not run asynchronously. You code below the forEach cannot run before forEach is done. It is assured. One more thing is you dont have to do a `return false` in the forEach iteration function. It is of no use in your case, it will still run the entire loop even if your first item matches the condition.

i think you probably misunderstood [forEach](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.forEach) to be an asynchronous operation possibly because of the function you registered. It is just an iteration function that you can use to evaluate each iteration.

Example for asynchronous functions is `$timeout` (setTimeout), `$interval` (setInterval), promise callbacks,  ajax call backs, animationFrames etc...